# CMake - Wrong _INCLUDE_DIR from find_path & Wrong _LIB_DIR from find_library

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, cmake

Using : `CMake 3.13.2` 
I am trying to create a `FindLibrary.cmake` file in order to find a library.
I have 2 issues :

1. **`find_path()`:** When I try to get the include directory from find_path using this
   command :
   `find_path(LIBTOFIND_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES include/headers/header.h
                PATHS ENV LIBTOFIND)`

   When I print `LIBTOFIND_INCLUDE_DIR` I get : `<LIBTOFIND>` only instead of : `<LIBTOFIND>/include/headers/` -- `LIBTOFIND` is an environment variable.
2. **`find_library()`:** When I try to find the libraries using the following command : 
    `find_library(LIBTOFIND_LIB NAMES lib/libversion/LibName
   PATHS ENV LIBTOFIND)` The library isn't found So I had to change it to this command :
   `find_library(LIBTOFIND_LIB NAMES lib/libversion/LibName.lib
   PATHS ENV LIBTOFIND)`
   As you can see : I had to mention the full name of the library, something I didn't see in any other `FindLibrary.cmake` file online. 
   The solution is generated (After trying some hardcode on the headers or part 1 of this question) but I can't run the project in visual studio for the following error : 
    `LNK1104  cannot open file 'LibName.lib'`

**Does this have anything to do with the cmake version ? or do you have any clue why I am getting these results ?**

Comment: ***Does this have anything to do with the cmake version ?*** I don't think so.

Comment: I don't understand what are you writing in the CMakeLists.txt, can you please post something more close to your real code plz? For example, PATHS ENV remains the sames, but LIBTOFIND is something different, right?

Comment: I'd imagine this isn't working because the path of the object being searched for is being included as part of the filename.  So in the first case it could have found `include/headers/header.h` in <root_folder>.  I think that the `include/headers` should be listed as part of `PATH_SUFFIXES` to work correctly.

Comment: `FindSDL_sound.cmake` seems to be a good example of using `PATH_SUFFIXES`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the **first** point, using `HINTS` and `PATH_SUFFIXES` as suggested by [Fred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1028434/fred) works better. According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_path.html) `PATHS` is the hardcoded path "guess" which points to where the header might be. So instead, `HINTS` and `PATH_SUFFIXES` must be used. `HINTS` gives an idea of where to look (Environment variable in my case), and `PATH_SUFFIXES` specifies additional subdirectories (of `LIBTOFIND` in this case) to check.

```
find_path(LIBTOFIND_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES header.h
       HINTS 
           ENV LIBTOFIND
       PATH_SUFFIXES include/headers/)
```

For the **second** point, I am not sure exactly why I should specify the extension, For it seems that is quite normal. What I don't understand is why others don't specify it and still it works.